# SharePoint through Web Client Service (webclnt.dll). CreateFile fails

Tags: sharepoint, webclient, createfile

I have an application that creates and edits documents.  I need to integrate it with SharePoint, so that users can edit files on SharePoint servers using my application.  My environment is Visual C++, non-MFC Windows application.

I'm trying out the Web Client service (webclnt.dll) to see if I can get my app to work with a minimum of code changes.  This works brilliantly with notepad, etc (just giving it a URL to the sharepoint document, Web Client intercepts the file I/O request and redirects it out to the network)... but my application is failing calling CreateFile with "GetLastError" code of 123:

```
(ERROR_INVALID_NAME).
```

Anyone know why this is?  I'm passing CreateFile a valid full URL to the file. I've looked through the options that can be passed to createFile and I don't see anything that looks like it would relax the filename validation.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to Create the file? That may help us figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you can't pass a URL to CreateFile.  You have to use the GetOpenFileName dialog, and enter a URL into that.  The WebDAV redirector then converts that into a URI that can be passed to CreateFile.  It works then.